# Not able to see an added component in the existing components list in strapi

Tags: javascript, json, strapi

I have created a component in the components section and named it "hero_type_1", now I want to create a parent component and want to use the previous component as an attribute but now I am unable to see the added component in the existing components select box.

[image]

After going through the Strapi forum I got to know that that I can add it manually in the json code, but just want to understand why it is not available there in the list and how can I make it available here without doing anything manually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i think strapi only supports nesting of components up to 2 levels deep in the admin dashboard. You can do more levels, but you would need to do that manually in the schema JSON files and are not able to manage these components via the admin dashboard.

They said it is because of performance concerns, but personally I think it would be a must have, since it's extremely limited with only 2 levels, but I do manage these via the JSON file, since there is no easy way to change that for now.